# In which order to rebase several differently old branches onto master?

Tags: git, markdown, git-rebase, pandoc

I searched through the [Git docu](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) and the [Tower tutorial](http://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/mac/advanced-topics/rebase) about rebasing, but didn't find a suitable advice. Does the age of branches maybe not matter, if there are no conflicts? If it does, is is there a general recommendation or rule of thumb, which branch to rebase first or last?

Scenario: writing a thesis, and having worked on different chapters/files in parallel, each a different branch. On the master branch, only configurations like pandoc or LaTeX package settings were changed, but all changes need to be integrated into that branch eventually. If in doubt, I'll merge, but I'm curious about rebase advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule of thumb. Because only you know the changes that you have in each branch.

If touched the same lines in different branches, you will have conflicts. No matter the order you decide, you will.

Choose a order that has some logic/common sense for your purpose.

Recommendation, when you rebase, you do not lose the old commits.
What happens is that new commits with the same changes are created. If before the rebasing you create a temporal branch. You have a kind of "backup" in the case of something goes wrong.

```
git checkout branchToRebase
git branch tmp
git rebase master
gitk --all& // you will see here both, old commits and new ones.
```

If everything went as you expected, you only have to remove this temporal branch.

```
git branch -D tmp
```

You need the uppercase "d" because git will warn you that these commits are going to be deattached from any reference.